# How to get just the image file name from a file field?

Tags: templates, file-uploads, xml

I'm setting up an xml page in which I need to have just the file name of an image from a file upload field. What I currently have is:

```
<picture>
    {exp:xml_encode}{image}{/exp:xml_encode}
</picture>
```

but what this results in is:

```
<picture>
http://domain.com/uploads/images/11-january-006.jpg
</picture>
```

When what I only need is 11-january-006.jpg

any ideas on the best approach for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [file field tag pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#variable-pair-usage):

```
{image}{file_name}{/image}
```

No add-on required!

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about that option.

Answer (score 0):

Does the [filename variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/file/file_tag.html#filename) not work for you?

```
{filename}
```

Comment: Nate,
nope but I found an addon that does what I need. Should've looked first before posting. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/jco-get-file-info

Comment: That only works within the `{exp:file:entries}` tag, which has different syntax from the File fieldtype tag pair (for some crazy reason).

Comment: It's the easy questions that you need to slow down on before answering, nice catch :)